# Select Dropdown based on the partial value in dropdown value field

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a scenario where i have to select the drop value based on querystring.

Query string could be like`q=c-1` `q=c-2` `q=p-5`

and value in drop-down could be `value="8-P-5"` `value="5-G-0"` `value="7-P-7"`

How can i select the drop-down value based on query-string

Is it possible to do it from Code-behind C# or jquery is easy solution.

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlOptionGroup" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlOptionGroup" class="form-control">
    <option value="1-C-1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="4-C-2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="5-G-0">Item 3</option>
    <option value="7-P-7">Item 4</option>
    <option value="8-P-5">Item 5</option>
    <option value="10-C-4">Item 6</option>
    <option value="3-P-0">Item 7</option>
    <option value="2-P-0">Item 8</option>
    <option value="6-G-0">Item 9</option>

</select>
```

If query-string is `q=c-2` then this should be selected `<option value="4-C-2" selected>Item 2</option>`

Comment: Your questions seems unclear.. Could you please explain how exactly you are trying to map querystring value and option in select menu?

Comment: From page one i am passing value as query string `q=c-2` and on the other page i have to pre select the drop-down that partly matches the query string. I have Category Page & Project Page and ID of both can be same so to preselect to correctly select the item in the drop-down i am prefixing valie with C & P, C for Category & P for project

Comment: So, at any case `value` in `options` will be unique right?

Comment: Yes, to make it unique

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are open for a JavaScript/jQuery solution you can take the [`window.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) and then use a jQuery selector to find the option based on a [contains](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) condition in a specific select tag.

Do note that this assumes the value that comes in your `q` is uniquely identifiable in a `value` property of your select element. In your current dataset `q=p-0` will have both Item 7 AND Item 8 match. As you didn't provide a business rule for that case I left that here untouched.

Here is a snippet that demonstrate this:

```js
// use window.location.search
var search = '?q=p-5'; // window.location.search;
// handle possible search for this value ?foo=bar&q=p-5#fragment
var parms = search.substr(1).split('&');
for(var i=0; i< parms.length;i++)
{
  var keyValue= parms[i].split('=');
  if (keyValue[0] === "q" && keyValue.length > 0) {
    var value = keyValue[1].split('#');
    $('select > option[value*="' + value[0].toUpperCase() + '"]').prop('selected',true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlOptionGroup" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlOptionGroup" class="form-control">
    <option value="1-C-1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="4-C-2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="5-G-0">Item 3</option>
    <option value="7-P-7">Item 4</option>
    <option value="8-P-5">Item 5</option>
    <option value="10-C-4">Item 6</option>
    <option value="3-P-0">Item 7</option>
    <option value="2-P-0">Item 8</option>
    <option value="6-G-0">Item 9</option>

</select>
```

Comment: This great answer

Comment: @Learning @rene This will select option `2-P-0` for `?q=p-0`. In other words, the option having value `3-P-0`(Item 7) will never be selected.

Comment: @Tushar yes, that is up to the OP how they want to resolve that scenario. In the end their life would be much easier if the value that is on the query string actually matches exactly with a value in the options.  Providing a partial key can only give you a best-effort match. If there is business logic that can determine when to choose one over the other that needs to be added. I have expanded my answer to notify visitors of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = DropDownList1.Items.Count-1; i >0 ; i--)
        {
            if (DropDownList1.Items[i].Value.Contains("C-2"))
            {
                DropDownList1.Items[i].Selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
```

or you can do it by Linq syntax

```
DropDownList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                   .Where(x => x.Value.Contains("C-2"))
                   .LastOrDefault().Selected = true;
```